# Does Apple's iOS have a backup DNS server configuration?

Tags: dns, iphone, network, ios

Yesterday I experienced something interesting while setting up a Wi-Fi access point. The access point was connected to the Internet via a local modem (gateway), which had **no** DNS server address configured. The clients (Windows notebooks, Android phones, iPhones) successfully connected to the access point, and got their network configuration via DHCP, including the DNS server, which was the IP address of the local internet gateway (the modem). But no DNS servers were configured on the modem, so you couldn't surf the web as usual (only by typing in the IP address of a website so no DNS was necessary).

Only if I manually configured the DNS on a Windows machine in the wireless adapter settings, "normal" surfing was working again. Also Android clients couldn't access the Internet (I didn't try to configure DNS manually on a client).

But the iPhone surprised me (running the latest iOS): It could load any web page without troubles, albeit the DNS server (the local gateway) served via DHCP was not working, as there no DNS server was configured.

So my question is: **does the iPhone (or more precisely: iOS) have an additional, internal, backup DNS server address configured, which it uses if it gets no working DNS server address via DHCP?**

Comment: You would have to ask the phone providers this question as they would be the DNS provider.  Unless you disable the cellular capabiltiies iOS will first use the WiFI then fallback to cellular traffic

Comment: Do you mean the iPhone falls back to the cellular network, but still displays the Wi-Fi symbol, ableit not using Wi-Fi?

Comment: I stand by my original statement.

Comment: Seconded, @Ramhound is correct.

Comment: So iOS displays that it is connected to a Wi-Fi network, but doesn't actually transfer data via Wi-Fi but actually uses cellular (in case Wi-Fi does not offer DNS or even Internet access)?

Comment: @Christian - Its only fallback behavior.  In other words its only used if the WiFi is unable to perform the request.

Comment: @Ramhound: I really doubt that iOS tests results of DNS resolutions and based on them could switch to a different connection but I certainly do not say that this is not possible. Do you have any proof?

Comment: @Christian: Can you capture IP packets on the gateway to see what is really going on there? Alternatively iPhone can also theoretically communicate through a proxy defined by an IP address and the DNS resolutions would be performed by the proxy. Did other protocols than HTTP/HTTPS work on the iPhone? --- As an example [Opera Mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini) always communicates through special proxies.

Comment: @pabouk - Besides the fact iOS is able to streamless go from cellular network to a WiFi network? My proof is simply using the phone. I am actually shocked that Android does not do it either, I remember something different with my personal hate love relationship with that tricky robot.  Don't mistake what I said for something its not.  If the iOS is able to make the request because of some other WiFi setting it will use the primary connection.  Its only if that request fails will it failback to the cellular network.

Comment: You're probably experiencing DNS caching in iOS.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, it's a solution for bad DNS servers (or none): You can click on the "info" icon for the access point and override the DHCP settings, including DNS. IOS remembers the changes and will re-apply them the next time you connect to the same SSID.  I'm doing this now because my cell provider frequently "can't find the host www.website.TLD"